# How to access internal layers of a smart object layer using Photoshop

Tags: python, photoshop, layer

Having a PSD file, created by me for testing purposes, containing, along regular layers, a smart object layer, I want to access the layers inside the  embedded smart object using Photoshop library.

I suppose, one have to read smart object content data as if it is a PSD file, as a smart object is just another PSD file placed inside.
The objective for me is to access smart object and change one of its image layer.

Comment: I believe you'll need to open the smart object document for that (at least in JS it's like that)

Comment: Do you know how it is done in python, preferable using pytoshop library?

Comment: [psd-tools](https://pypi.org/project/psd-tools/)

Comment: @LeiYang psd-tools do not allows to modify/edit layers, being they smart or not.
Other than that psd-tools is really a valuable python lib.